# Error in Xamarin Android integrating Intercom

Tags: xamarin.android

Calling this method:

```
IntercomSdk.Intercom.Client().DisplayMessenger();
```

I get this exception:

```
[AndroidRuntime] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method onNestedFling(Landroid/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout;Landroid/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout;Landroid/view/View;FFZ)Z in class Landroid/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout$Behavior; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior' appears in /data/app/es.smartloto.smartloto-dvf2COkzGja7r9FkpKRG-Q==/base.apk
[AndroidRuntime]    at io.intercom.android.sdk.profile.ProfileCoordinator.flingCoordinator(ProfileCoordinator.java:191)
[AndroidRuntime]    at io.intercom.android.sdk.profile.ProfileCoordinator.profileAutoOpened(ProfileCoordinator.java:175)
[AndroidRuntime]    at io.intercom.android.sdk.conversation.ConversationFragment.sdkWindowFinishedAnimating(ConversationFragment.java:643)
[AndroidRuntime]    at io.intercom.android.sdk.activities.IntercomMessengerActivity$3.onAnimationEnd(IntercomMessengerActivity.java:244)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator$AnimatorEventListener.onAnimationEnd(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:1122)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(Animator.java:552)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1209)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1449)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(AnimationHandler.java:146)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.animation.AnimationHandler.-wrap2(Unknown Source:0)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame(AnimationHandler.java:54)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:909)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:655)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I tested different options to try to solve the problem but I couldn't find the solution. 
I appreciate your help, thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for your problem?

Comment: No, I couldn't find anything yet

Comment: Same problem here, I have tried to deactivate linker which also did not help. Do the push notifications work for you? Because for me it also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the error.

It occurs if you have a newer version of the android support libraries in your project than that the java aar was builded with.
Most bindings for Intercom use the Intercom Android SDK Version 3.0.XX, which was built against API Level 25 (Support libraries 25.XX.XX), I think.
I could solve the problem by creating my own bindings for the newest version of the Intercom Android SDK which are build against API Level 27, which I happen to use in my project.

Basicaly you have 2 option:

1. Create your own Bindings with the new Intercom Version
2. Downgrade your API Level and Support Libraries to Version 25.XX.XX

I might upload my Binding of the new Intercom Android SDK to github at some point, however it might take some time until I will be able do so.